# Does there exist a method of removing a single HTML tag and NOT the entire node?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code

```
<noscript>
<img src="url/HugeCatPicture.jpg" name="I dont want this image to auto load">
</noscript>
```

I wish to remove only the opening **noscript** tag and leave the closing noscript tag.

Can this be done with pure JavaScript?
Is such an action even possible?

*(No javascript library solutions please)*

Comment: can u do like `var a = '<noscript><img src="url/HugeCatPicture.jpg" name="I dont want this image to auto load"></noscript>' ; a.replace("<noscript>","")`

Comment: Why do you want to do that? The reason might lead you to a solution.

Comment: @debin Thanks, but I can not do what you are suggesting because the tags in my example are already hard written onto the html page. I need a method of removing at least one of the tags so that the img tag is once more accessible by the browser for loading.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @OriDrori I wish to remove one of the noScript tags because i can not access the contents wrapped within noScript tags. The reason i am using no script tags in the first place is to prevent large images from auto loading. I am optimizing a project that contains over 300 images on one page, i do not wish to add javascript to update the src of all 300+ images.

Answer (score 2):

Html document is node based, and if you delete `noscript` then it's child also gets removed. For this

1. read child elements of `noscript`
2. get `noscript` and it's parent DOM
3. remove `nosrcript` and append child elements to `noscript` parent node

Comment: That was the first thing i tried however; wrapping HTML elements within a noscript tag makes it's contents (child nodes) inaccessible by javascript UNLESS the browser does not have javascript enabled.

So this answer will not help.

Comment: @ReallyNiceCode, can you read your comment again and explain it to me ? How that UNLESS part can ever happen ? + you can access the noscript element and its `textContent` or `innerHTML`

Comment: then you need to use `<img>` in different way. write script that prevent auto loading of `<img>`. I just said to by reading `alt` attribute.

Comment: @Kaiido in simple terms: "JavaScript can not simply read the child elements of a <noscript> tag. So this answer will not work. Please run a simple test to see what i am talking about!

Comment: @ReallyNiceCode, yes it can *read* its content, but this content is not part of the DOM, so you can't use direct DOM selection on it. However, you can access the textContent of this node and parse it. https://jsfiddle.net/zqesf6p5/ But this is way worse than adding an data-attribute on your imgs before setting their src. Modifying the DOM structure 300 times is not a good idea if you are concerned about performances.

Comment: @Kaiido Thanks, now i can access the elements contained within the noscript tags as a text string. Using the textContent results in plain text being added to the page, so i will just devise a way of getting it parsed. thanks alot for the help.

Comment: @Kaiido okay but why not? Any specific reason why that might be a bad idea?

Comment: @ReallyNiceCode Yes as I told you, Accessing and modifying the DOM structure is one of the worse operation you can do. While storing your wanted srcs as data-attributes and just setting your imgs src to it later-on consumes almost nothing. Also, this is not in accordance to how this tag should be used. This is just a really bad idea and not a Really Nice Code by any means.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that this is improper use of the `<noscript>` tag. From the [W3C documentation](https://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/noscript) about `noscript`:

> The noscript element is used to present different markup to user agents that don’t support scripting

Comment: Thanks, I know that the <noscript> tag was meant to provide fallback content to browsers that do not support javaScript or have javaScript disabled. But i am using it as an optimization hack. I wish to prevent <img> tags from auto loading its images.. but i do not wish to manually edit over 300 tags. 

Wrapping the image tags within the noscript tags was successful at stopping the images from auto loading... but now i am unable to dynamically access the contents within the noscript tags.

Comment: The solution is to not use it as an optimization hack, because it's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pure javascript as :

```
<script>
  // on page reload use this
 var str = '<noscript><img src="image_url" name="test"></noscript>' 
 var res = str.replace("<noscript>", "");
 document.getElementById("your_id").innerHTML = res;
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks but your solution implies that i am dynamically adding the <noscript> tag with javascript... instead i am hard coding the <noscript> tag onto the page; then upon page load i wish to use javascript to remove one of the noscript tags.